# python django pass post request data into dictionary

Tags: python, django

There is a POST request that sends data to django. python 3.7

```
if request.method=="POST":
    print(request.data)
```

this prints out

```
<QueryDict: {'file_id': ['2019_08_07_12_17_44.943792.csv'], 'HouseNumber': [''], 'Street': ['Address'], 'Borough': ['Boro'], 'ZipCode': ['Zip']}>
```

for this file submission. I need to turn this querydict into a python dictionary. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.dict) says you can easily use `.dict()`

```py
request.data.dict()
```